# CRUD json with java servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have a Dog class which has name, age and height values. I want to create a JSON object with these values. Then, I want to create the methods `CreateJsonServlet`, `ModifyJsonServlet` and `DeleteJsonServlet`. I need to generate a JSON object and then pass it to create, update and delete JSON methods.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CreateServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.doPost(req, resp);

    Dog dog = new Dog();

    dog.setName(req.getParameter("name"));
    dog.setHeight(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("height")));
    dog.setAge(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("age")));


    String name = dog.getName();
    int age = dog.getAge();
    int height = dog.getHeight();



    resp.getWriter().write(dog.toString());
    resp.getWriter().flush();
    resp.getWriter().close();

}
```

}

This is the Dog class:

```
package com.Google;

public class Dog {

private String name;
private int age;
private int height;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Dog{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", height=" + height +
            '}';
}
```

}

Comment: Read about JAXB marshalling

Comment: Is there any special reason for using Servlets? It could be achieved with JAX-RS.

Comment: yes, I have a task and it must be with servlets.